# How to create Custom Fields on Standard Objects in the package.xml

Tags: custom-field, metadata, standard-objects

I want to add custom fields to the Contact Object in SFDC. When I look into the package.xml I do not see any of these changes or fields. I am missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need two things here.

**1** - Add the custom field in the metadata definition of the Contact Object, as below:

```
<CustomObject ...>
   <fields>
         <fullName>MyField__c</fullName>
         .. all other tags ..
     </fields>
 </CustomObject>
```

**2** - Add your Contact object in the `package.xml` as:

```
<types>
    <members>Contact</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

---

Refer to the documentation for details.

- [Sample package.xml Manifest Files](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/manifest_samples.htm)
- [CustomField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm)

Comment: It should be the Contact's metadata xml file. Should be under `<your-directory>/objects/Contact.object`.

Comment: If I do step 2 two first, then the object shows up. Changes to the object in the UI don't make the Contact Metadata show up. This works though thank you!