# Adding a custom field to standard object activity

Tags: metadata-api, custom-field, custom-metadata, metadata-relationship

I would like to add a custom Date field to a standard Activity object. Lets say this date field is called 'food_expiration__c'. Looking at another question: [How to create Custom Fields on Standard Objects in the package.xml](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235204/how-to-create-custom-fields-on-standard-objects-in-the-package-xml)

So I go to to Activity.object and add to the existing fields:

```
<fields>
        <fullName>food_expiration__c</fullName>
        <description>When food expires</description>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>Food Expiration Date</label>
        <required>false</required>
        <type>DateTime</type>
    </fields>
```

Then I open my deployment package.xml and see the following two custom classes that I had modified:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <members>Custom_Class1</members>
    <members>Custom_Class2</members>
    <name>ApexClass</name>
  </types>
  <version>47.0</version>
</Package>
```

Am I to then add the following :
Activity

so that when I deploy that this custom field exist ?

Sorry I cant try it at the moment but mostly trying to understand how it is done right

Comment: Have you tried to add Activity as ``CustomField`` type and see what happens? You have everything you need in the question you provided a link to.

Answer (score 1):

Object metadata is deployed via entities of type `CustomObject` in the Metadata API / `package.xml`.

You'd include an entry like this:

```
 <types>
    <members>Activity</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
  </types>
```

and, of course, you'll have to have the `Activity.object` file in your source directory.